# redirect to url does not work after ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do the following:

Pass a variable to flask from ajax that is posted in an input field, and when flask gets it and inserts it into a mysql table, I'd like to redirect the url to a new page whose content is modified by the user entered text in the input field. The flask gets the variable (heheh) inserts it into mysql, so that works fine.

My problem is that the redirect does not happen, I get the following error:

`{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

What can be the problem? Thanks

```
$("#searcher").click(function(){
                console.log('foo11');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{url_for('pubfd')}}",
                    data : JSON.stringify({'data': 'heheh'}),
                    contentType: "application/json", // this
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                            window.location.href = "http://43.234.32.9/index";
                            console.log('fo23o11');
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errormessage) {
                        console.log("-----ERROR: -----", errormessage);
                        console.log("-----ERROR2: -----", jqXHR);

                        console.log("-----ERROR3: -----", textStatus);
                    }
                });
                console.log('foo2');
            });
```

I got ERROR3 : parseerror

flask code:

```
@app.route("/blic", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pubfd():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("fooldal.html")
    clicked = "---"
    if request.method == "POST":
        clicked=request.json['data']
        print("ez a clickedd", clicked)
    return "ok"
```

Comment: Why did you add two success method? Please remove one and try again.

Comment: @Pranab Done, thanks!

Comment: The "error" that you posted is not an error - it's the return value of the ajax call.  Do you also see the console output "fo23o11"?

Comment: The error message is the third argument to the `error:` function, not the first argument. The first argument is just the `jqXHR` object.

Comment: So it should be `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errormessage)`

Comment: I got textstatus: parsererror in the console

Comment: What does this: `{{url_for('pubfd')}}` resolve to?  If you view source in the browser, is that rendering the correct URL?

Answer (score 1):

By removing dataType: "json" the redirect worked.